# How do I serialise JSON keys in a Python list?

Tags: python, json

I want to iterate through a JSON file using Python and print the a set of keys.

For example:

```
import json

KEYS_TO_PRINT = ["id", "channel.title"]
my_data = {"items": [{"id": 1, "channel": {"channelid": "channelid1", "title": "nailed_it1"}}, {"id": 2, "channel": {"channelid": "channelid2", "title": "nailed_it2"}}]}
this_row = []

for item in my_data["items"]:
    for key in KEYS_TO_PRINT:
        try:
            if "." in key:
                split_up = key.split(".")
                print item[split_up[0]][split_up[1]]
            else:
                print item[key]
        except KeyError:
            print "Oops"
```

However, it's pretty ugly. Is there a neater way?

Comment: Can you add the JSON file (or subset of) that you are using?  And the expected output?

Comment: What you want to do is unclear. You say "but then I have 'subkeys'(?)", what do you want to happen? Example input and output might be useful...

Comment: I know this is unrelated to the question but take a look at item.get() syntax, it will save you a try/except

Comment: If you're dealing with JSON in Python, I highly recommend the fantastic Requests library: http://docs.python-requests.org
Makes a lot of the worries regarding JSON interpretation moot.

Comment: See my comment below - in that example, I'd expect to see "nailed_it1" and "nailed_it2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider something like this, you can specify a subkey using "." to delimit your keys. Here's an example:

```
KEYS_TO_EXPORT = ["id", "dateTime", "title", "channel.title"]
item = {"id": 1, "channel": {"title": "nailed_it"}}
this_row = []
for export_key in KEYS_TO_EXPORT:
    try:
        value = item
        for key in export_key.split("."):
            value = value[key]
        this_row.append(str(value).encode('utf-8'))
    except KeyError:
        this_row.append("")
```

**Edit to work with list:**

This solution can easily be extended to work with a list of items as per the edit to the original question as follows. Also I switched to using `.get` like Will suggested in the comments.

```
KEYS_TO_PRINT = ["id", "channel.title"]
my_data = {"items": [
    {"id": 1, "channel": {"channelid": "channelid1", "title": "nailed_it1"}},
    {"id": 2, "channel": {"channelid": "channelid2", "title": "nailed_it2"}},
    {"id": 3}
]}
this_row = []

for item in my_data["items"]:
    for export_key in KEYS_TO_PRINT:
        value = item
        for key in export_key.split("."):
            value = value.get(key)
            if value == None: break
        this_row.append(str(value).encode('utf-8') if value != None else "")
print this_row
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me:KEYS_TO_EXPORT = ["channel.title"]
item = {"id": 1, "channel": {id: "channelid1", "title": "nailed_it1"}, "id": 2, "channel": {id: "channelid2", "title": "nailed_it2"}}
this_row = []
for export_key in KEYS_TO_EXPORT:
    try:
        value = item
        for key in export_key.split("."):
            value = value[key]
        this_row.append(str(value).encode('utf-8'))
        print this_row
    except KeyError:
        this_row.append("")

Comment: If you expect it to print "nailed_it1" and "nailed_it2", it certainly cannot. The dictionary you pass it is malformed, all the keys in a dictionary must be unique. It's not possible to have two values for a single key, so the second value you define for the key is what gets used which is why this only prints "nailed_it2".

Comment: please see amended example; you're right that my original example wasn't great.

Comment: The edit is fantastic (need a few indentation changes, but this solution definitely works!). Thanks!